# Arduino Python Serial mouse click

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

I'm trying to make when serial is available Mouse_click(left) and if serial is not available don't click but my code is clicking continously i can't stop it.

Arduino side :

```
   #include <Mouse.h>


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Mouse.begin();
}
void serial_flush_buffer() {
    while (Serial.read() >= 0);
}
void loop() {
  while (Serial.available()> 0){
    Mouse.click(MOUSE_LEFT);
    serial_flush_buffer();
    break;

  }
  }
```

Python side:

```
import serial
arduino = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600)
arduino.write(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to empty the serial,

> serial.Available: Get the number of bytes (characters) available for reading from the serial port. This is data that’s already arrived and stored in the serial receive buffer (which holds 64 bytes).

So you might want to create a function that empty it like:

```
void serial_flush_buffer() {
    while (Serial.read() >= 0);
}
```

EDIT:

From what I can see your python code only send one char.

```
arduino.write(2)
```

So you might want to write that in a loop like this:

```
import serial
import time
arduino = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600)
while True:
    arduino.write(2)
    time.sleep(1) # to avoid overload the buffer
```

Comment: I did but now it is not reading new serial inputs i mean it is clicks one time then stops forever can you check the edited code on thread ?